# Columns name for dictionary key and values using Pandas

Tags: python, excel, pandas

I am using pandas to dump some data into excel file. The data is in dictionary format and I am using the following code to dump it.

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(weights_dict, orient="index")
df1.columns = ['weights']
```

I am getting the following output

```
             | weights
------------------------
D1_sum       |  8
U2_conv      |  9
y1_maxpool   |  10
y22_dropout  |  11
```

I want to set a name to the first column as well. How can I do that? Thanks.

Expected output:

```
  Layers     | weights
------------------------
D1_sum       |  8
U2_conv      |  9
y1_maxpool   |  10
y22_dropout  |  11
```

EDIT:

After using

```
df.index.name = 'Layer'
```

I get the following result:

```
             | weights
------------------------
Layer        |
------------------------
D1_sum       |  8
U2_conv      |  9
y1_maxpool   |  10
y22_dropout  |  11
```

Using the rename_axis gives following error:

```
 File "C:\ENV\p34\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\generic.py", line 573, in rename
    result._data = result._data.rename_axis(f, axis=baxis, copy=copy)
  File "C:\ENV\p34\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\internals.py", line 2233, in rename_axis
    obj.set_axis(axis, _transform_index(self.axes[axis], mapper))
  File "C:\ENV\p34\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\internals.py", line 3982, in _transform_index
    items = [func(x) for x in index]
  File "C:\ENV\p34\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\internals.py", line 3982, in <listcomp>
    items = [func(x) for x in index]
TypeError: 'str' object is not callable
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use set columns names or index name or both:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'weights': [8, 9, 10, 11]}, 
                   index=['D1_sum', 'U2_conv', 'y1_maxpool', 'y22_dropout']) 
print (df)
             weights
D1_sum             8
U2_conv            9
y1_maxpool        10
y22_dropout       11


df.index.name = 'Layers1'
df.columns.name = 'Layers2'

print (df)
Layers2      weights
Layers1             
D1_sum             8
U2_conv            9
y1_maxpool        10
y22_dropout       11
```

Another solution with [`rename_axis`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.rename_axis.html):

```
df = df.rename_axis('Layers1').rename_axis('Layers2', axis=1)

print (df)
Layers2      weights
Layers1             
D1_sum             8
U2_conv            9
y1_maxpool        10
y22_dropout       11
```

---

```
df.columns.name = 'Layers'
print (df)
Layers       weights
D1_sum             8
U2_conv            9
y1_maxpool        10
y22_dropout       11

df = df.rename_axis('Layers', axis=1)
print (df)
Layers       weights
D1_sum             8
U2_conv            9
y1_maxpool        10
y22_dropout       11
```

Possible solution if need column name in Excel:

```
#set index name
df.index.name = 'Layer'
#reset index - index values create new column
df = df.reset_index()
print (df)
         Layer  weights
0       D1_sum        8
1      U2_conv        9
2   y1_maxpool       10
3  y22_dropout       11

#write df to excel, remove default index (0,1,2,3)
df.to_excel('file.xlsx', index=False)
```

Comment: Thanks. However, is it possible to have just one cell with "Layer" and adjacent to "weights" cell for e.g `| Layers | Weights |`

Comment: Sorry, I dont explain it very nice. So I edit answer.

Comment: Thanks again! For some reason `df.columns.name = 'Layer' ` code has no effect for me. `df.index.name= 'Layer' ` adds the Layer cell to the column but not in correct format. I have updated the question with the output.

Comment: What return `print(df.columns.name)` ?

Comment: Its `none`. I even checked on debugger. The value of columns is none, even though I have set it.

Comment: I think you use old version of pandas.

Comment: `print (pd.show_versions())` check it. Last version is `0.19.2`

Comment: ok now it shows the value on console, but it isn't present in excel file `Out[3]: 'Layers' ; df1.columns.name
`

Comment: I also add test dataframe to answer.

Comment: So `rename_axis` was implemented in `0.18.0` - check [here](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/whatsnew.html#changes-to-rename)

Comment: In excel file? I think `to_excel` omit it. I add possible solution.

Comment: It works now. Thanks alot for your efforts and help!! Cheers!